# how pass multiple params in url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I´m trying to make a custom path for a project, I send the ID and a month and year to display some data, this those params were sended with a form_for and make a terrible url:
`http://localhost:3000/havings_discount_record/employee?utf8=%E2%9C%93&having%5Bemployee_id%5D=1&having%5Bhavings_month%5D=7&having%5Bhavings_year%5D=2019&commit=Busqueda`

I tried to change my route from:

```
get 'havings_discount_record/employee', to: 'havings_discount_record#record_per_employee', as: 'record_per_employee'
```

to:
`get 'havings_discount_record/employee/:employee_id/:havings_month/:havings_year', to: 'havings_discount_record#record_per_employee', as: 'record_per_employee'`
But then I remember that don´t work in that way, data is sended after press a submit button

```
 <%= form_for @havings, url: record_per_employee_path, method: :get  do |data| %>
    <%= data.text_field :employee_id %>
    <%= data.text_field :havings_month %>
    <%= data.text_field :havings_year %>
    <%= data.submit "Busqueda"%>
  <% end %>
```

I want to keep url as simple as possible, only showing something like:

`http://localhost:3000/havings_discount_record/employee/1/7/2019`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I tried other thing, I make a method in my controller (this is a reduced example) in this way:

```
def search
  @employee_id = params[:legal_vacation][:employee_id]
  redirect_to employee_pool_path(@employee_id)
end
```

I make a route and send my form data to this method, in this way you can use a single :id in your app and avoid a monstrous query string. 
I hope this can help you in the future or past, or whatever. If you find another way let me know.